# android resource specifiers - avoiding image duplication

Tags: android

I am making a game for android which uses a large number of images.

I have a set of images that I would like to use for 480x800 ish resolutions (i.e. large devices or normal hdpi/xhdpi devices). Another set of images I should like to use for normal mdpi, normal ldpi and small devices of any dpi.

My problem is this. I could copy the images into many different folders which would give me the desired functionality. However, this would make my .apk too large. I could also create resource aliases using xml. However, with the amount of images, I'm looking at having to create hundreds of xml files manually.

Any ideas on how to accomplish the following more conveniently? I noticed they have introduced new resource specifiers that would solve my problem in API level 13, but I need this to work on android 2.1+

Answer (score 0):

There are resource specifiers in android 2.1+ they were just changed to handle different parameters that better suited android becoming both a tablet and phone platform.

The old specifiers were drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-ldpi.

drawable-xhdpi was added to support larger screen sizes in Android 2.2.